# What is causing random highlighting on a Semantic UI Component on Safari?

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am running into an issue in my React application where there is random highlighting when I click on a Semantic UI menu component when running on Safari 12.1.2. I have screenshot the issue below. For some reason, the random highlighting always exists and only gets thicker or thinner depending on if I've clicked on the Menu.Item component.

[Random Highlighting thicker after clicking on Menu.Item component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3Efh.png)

[Random Highlighting thinner after clicking outside of Menu.Item component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOB5H.png)

I've tried switching the Menu component into a Button Semantic UI component to see if issue still exists, and it still does. So it does not seem to be tied to the Menu component itself.

This does not happen on Chrome and Firefox. Can anybody lead me in the right direction as to what styling setting could be causing this issue just on Safari?

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured it out and it was caused by a div wrapper of my Menu component with an attribute of tab index. The tab index attribute in semantic ui is has a background color on selection. So I have inserted this into the .css and it works.

```
[tabindex] {
    outline: none;
}
```